# Getting Locations without some types? Google Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

is it possible to get locations that are points of interest and not lodging, restaurant, etc in the Google Places API?

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=" + latitude + "," + longtitude + "&radius="+radius+"&sensor=true&type=point_of_interest=" + GOOGLE_KEY
```

that is what it looks like when I'm getting points of interest, but it also returns locations that are points of interest AND lodging, restaurant etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you get the callback from the API with all the locations that are listed as POI, you could parse each item to see if that is the only listed tag, and remove any ones that have more tags from your data set. I don't believe there is a way to exclude certain tags, though I may be wrong. I tried to use the Places API once......it was the first and last time I'll be using it.